# How to send attachment using AWS SES in NodeJS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

As per the given doc at "[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SES.html#sendTemplatedEmail-property](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SES.html)". It was using "**sendTemplatedEmail**" API we can send email using templates. It was successful. But I could not figure out how to add attachments to it.

In the 4th point of the "**sendTemplatedEmail**" API doc it says "The total size of the message, including attachments, must be less than 10 MB". How to add the attachment here in this sendTemplatedEmail API?

Also there is a API called "**sendRawEmail**". But that does not suit my requirement. I need to use templates and also attach documents. Does any one know what to do ??

Comment: Did you find a solution to send attachment with template email?

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti Did you find a solution to send attachment with template email??

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the SendRawEmail example:

```
/* The following example sends an email with an attachment: */

 var params = {
     Destinations: [], 
     FromArn: "", 
     RawMessage: {
         Data: <Binary String>
     }, 
     ReturnPathArn: "", 
     Source: "", 
     SourceArn: ""
 };
 ses.sendRawEmail(params, function(err, data) {
     if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
     else     console.log(data);           // successful response
     /*
     data = {
         MessageId: "EXAMPLEf3f73d99b-c63fb06f-d263-41f8-a0fb-d0dc67d56c07-000000"
     }
     */
 });
```

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SES.html

Important: you need to understand the MIME type standards to include your attachment. Take a look at [this article](https://computer.howstuffworks.com/question334.htm).

> MIME was defined in 1992 by the Internet Engineering Task Force
>   (IETF). The distinguishing characteristic of a MIME message is the
>   presence of the MIME headers. As long as your mail recipients also
>   have e-mail software that is MIME-compliant (and most e-mail software
>   is), you can swap files containing attachments automatically.

EDIT: [This article](https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/internet/email/article.php/c3405/EMail-File-Attachments-Using-MIME.htm) explains how to include attachment in your body.

> MIME completes the illusion of file attachments by allowing the
>   message body to be divided into distinct parts, each with their own
>   headers. The content type multipart/mixed means that the content of
>   the body is divided into blocks separated by "--" + a unique string
>   guaranteed to not be found anywhere else in the message. If you say
>   that your boundary string is "MyBoundaryString", then all occurrences
>   of that string will be treated as a boundary. So it better not be in
>   the message the user typed or it won't be decoded correctly.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) also gives an example:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=frontier

This is a message with multiple parts in MIME format.
--frontier
Content-Type: text/plain

This is the body of the message.
--frontier
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

PGh0bWw+CiAgPGhlYWQ+CiAgPC9oZWFkPgogIDxib2R5PgogICAgPHA+VGhpcyBpcyB0aGUg
Ym9keSBvZiB0aGUgbWVzc2FnZS48L3A+CiAgPC9ib2R5Pgo8L2h0bWw+Cg==
--frontier--
```

I assume you are familiar with [Base64](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

Comment: Email attachments are not a separate item. Attachments are actually embedded inside the body (the text) of your email using special markers. Google search Email MIME attachments. If you understand MIME, it is very easy to add attachments to an email.

Comment: @JohnHanley, thanks -- just updated the answer with more details.

Comment: Nice improvements.

Comment: @JohnHanley and FabioManZano Thanks, I understand that we must use MIME format and base64. This is cool for API "sendRawEmail". But i want to use the template feature here. Its like there is an HTML file. I will replace certain text in the HTML and then send it. Isnt it there as an option in AWS SES?

Comment: If you want to include attachments with SES, then you need to use `sendRawEmail` to do so. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2011/07/18/amazon-simple-email-service-announces-attachment-support/

Comment: It seems that [createTemplate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SES.html#createTemplate-property) is limited to HTML. Alternatively, you can send a link to a file in S3.

Comment: So, you say AWS hasn't provided any way to use templated emails and attachments at the same time. To conclude, I have to use the "sendRawEmail"  to send attachment. Hmmm

Comment: It doesn't seems to provide. Again, you can contact their support, but by their documentation, it seems that sendRawEmail it the only choice. Again, you can always create a template with a link to an S3 object for download. Hope it helps and answers your question.

Comment: How to I add a second attachment? If I add a second block with `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` only the first attachment ever comes in with my email...

Comment: Check Multipart Content-Type: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html